# New rails 6.1.1.3 app misconfigured webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm running nodejs 16 on ubuntu 20.04 I created a new rails 6.1.1.3 app and then ran `npx webpack serve --mode=development`
and got the following errors:
warning " > @webpack-cli/serve@1.3.1" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack-cli@4.x.x".
TypeError: Class constructor ServeCommand cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69046801/brand-new-rails-6-1-4-1-fails-with-webpack-error-typeerror-class-constructor). You'll probably need to downgrade to `webpack-dev-server` version 3 and remove `@webpack-cli/serve` from your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the error, I can only offer a similar solution that I encountered. I kept getting errors on the latest dot release of nodejs on a few new apps. I uninstalled node js 16 and went back to the LTS release of 14.16.1 and that cleared up all of my issues. So unless you have a feature that requires 16, I would try stepping back to the LTS release which Node also denotes is going to be more stable with less problems.

Comment: When I ran `rails webpacker:install` I got an error that webpacker doesn't run on node 14

Comment: Thanks that's what I did

Comment: My node version is 16 and bootstrap is working in other rails 6 apps