# Brand new Rails 6.1.4.1 fails with webpack error - TypeError: Class constructor ServeCommand cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

A brand new Rails 6.1.4.1 app fails to run `bin/webpack-dev-server` with the following error:

```
/rails_app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/prompt-command.js:46
    return func(...args);
           ^

TypeError: Class constructor ServeCommand cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at runWhenInstalled (/rails_app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/prompt-command.js:46:9)
    at promptForInstallation (/rails_app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/prompt-command.js:140:10)
    at /rails_app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:32:43
    at Object.<anonymous> (/rails_app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot determine what the question is based on this post. Can you please update explaining the problem you are facing, an error or stack trace of some kind and some way to possibly reproduce it or at least what method or command is causing it?

Comment: Posting as a comment, not an answer, because it's just a workaround ... I backed my versions down to `"@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",` and `"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"` to get back to a functional webpacker. Also related, for anyone hunting this down further: https://dev.to/arisa_dev/webpack-cli-would-you-like-to-install-webpack-cli-yes-no-crash-to-solve-526l

Comment: James Chevalier: OK Let me know if you find out when I can upgrade from there This is really crazy Maybe I shouldn't be using the newest rails versions

Answer (score 21):

[This reported issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43062) shows that webpack-dev-server is no longer compatible with Webpacker 5. This means that there are two fixes available to us:

1. Force webpack-dev-server to stay on version 3

You can do this by updating your `package.json` file:

```
"webpack-dev-server": "~3"
```

2. Upgrade to Webpacker 6

This version is [not yet released](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600---2021-tbd) and [the upgrade path](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/v6_upgrade.md) is not simple.

Comment: I found this workaround solution Uninstall system nodejs and install nvm and then use nvm to install nodejs again but now you can easily switch node versions in terminal sessions ```nvm add 16``` and ```nvm use 16.0.0``` Now since yarn add by default upgrades to the newest version run ```yarn add webpack/cli``` and then ```yarn add webpack-cli/serve``` Now you'll get error ./src not found ```mkdir src``` and then ```touch src/index.js``` After all that ```npx webpack serve``` works

Comment: I've since realized it's necessary to upgrade the rubygem webpacker to it's latest version after you've done all that

Comment: This can never be solved It's unpredictable behavior Stuck all over again on another app

Comment: There's also the matter of the rubygem webpacker and the npm module rails/webpacker and also the matter of there's webpack-cli component of webpack and if you install webpack-cli separately it seems to be creating a duplicate installation of webpack-cli with a different version

Comment: In my experiences with new and upgraded Rails apps, `package.json` sets `"@rails/webpacker": "5.4.2"` (which is ok and usable) and `"webpack-dev-server": "^4.1.0"` (which is not usable with Webpacker 5) and _only_ changing `^4.1.0` to `~3` was enough to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks I solved by downgrading webpack to 4.x.x because rails/webpacker 5.x.x is incompatible with webpack 5.x.x but works fine with 4.x.x I found this answer on github

Comment: webpack-dev-server is replaced by ```npx webpack serve --mode=development```

Comment: It worked option 1 just after do: 
1) npm cache clean --force
2) rmdir /S /Q node_modules (windows version)
3) npm install
4) "webpack-dev-server": "~3" (in the package.json file)
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I solved by downgrading webpack to 4.x.x because rails/webpacker 5.x.x is incompatible with webpack 5.x.x but works fine with 4.x.x I found this answer at this url on github https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11649#issuecomment-779781768

Comment: Consider adding a link to where specifically you found the answer on GitHub.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I found it's also necessary to run ```rails webpacker:install```

Comment: Also there's an activestorage migration when upgrading from rails 6 to rails 6.1

Answer (score 0):

You can watch this article at the end that explain how fix it: https://tundaapo.medium.com/the-web-as-a-means-of-communication-starting-with-rails-c10aa28b4fc2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As ***@Scott K*** suggested, I ran:

```
rails webpacker:install
```

and that fixed the issue.